# Change MySQL innodb_buffer_pool_size at runtime?

Tags: mysql, system-administration, reload

This may be a dumb question, but is it possible to change the MySQL configuration options such as  `innodb_buffer_pool_size` at runtime?

Or, equivalently, is there a way to reload MySQL without closing existing connections or refusing new connections (like you can do with Apache)?

Linux_32 (2.6.26) + MySQL 5.0.24a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this MySQL forum post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,113348,113399#msg-113399), it is not possible to set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` at runtime.

So the question remains: is it possible to change the MySQL configuration and reload the daemon transparently to its users?

Comment: Never found any evidence to support the idea, so I now believe it is not possible.

Comment: It is doable at runtime with MySQL >= 5.7.5. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29796591/1129978)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can (depending on your server version).

The innodb_buffer_pool_size is a dynamic variable since 5.7.5 as [this manual entry](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) says.

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html) is some further information about the server's behaviour when changing the size.

Comment: Worked for me on mysql 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1:
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=53687091200;

Comment: It is doable at runtime with MySQL >= 5.7.5. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29796591/1129978)