# How to set global innodb_buffer_pool_size?

Tags: mysql

How to set the global `innodb_buffer_pool_size` mySQL variable? When I set it to `system display` I get this error:

```
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' is a read only variable
```

Comment: What do you mean by "When I set it to `system display`"?  `inno_db_buffer_pool_size` should be a size, such as `16M`

Answer (score 26):

In the earlier versions of **MySQL ( < 5.7.5 )** the only way to set

> 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'

variable was by writing it to **my.cnf (for linux)** and **my.ini (for windows)** under [mysqld] section :

```
[mysqld]

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2147483648
```

*You need to restart your mysql server to have it's effect in action.*

### **UPDATE :**

> As of MySQL 5.7.5, the innodb_buffer_pool_size configuration option
>   can be set dynamically using a SET statement, allowing you to resize
>   the buffer pool without restarting the server. For example:
>
> ```
> mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=402653184;
> ```

Reference : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-online-resize.html

#### Note

> Buffer pool size must always be equal to or a multiple of
>   innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances. If you
>   configure innodb_buffer_pool_size to a value that is not equal to or a
>   multiple of innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size *
>   innodb_buffer_pool_instances, buffer pool size is automatically
>   adjusted to a value that is equal to or a multiple of
>   innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances that is
>   not less than the specified buffer pool

**By @FlyingAtom**

Comment: Can i type SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=1.5GB;

Comment: The [**documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-online-resize.html) says : Buffer pool size must always be equal to or a multiple of innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances. If you configure innodb_buffer_pool_size to a value that is not equal to or a multiple of innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances, buffer pool size is automatically adjusted to a value that is equal to or a multiple of innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances that is not less than the specified buffer pool size. @FlyingAtom

Comment: So, if **1.5G** is `>= innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances` then you can set such value otherwise it will be automatically adjusted as stated above. @FlyingAtom

Comment: If you want to increase pool size by X - this worked for me
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size= (SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size)*10
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024

Answer (score 7):

innodb_buffer_pool_size

You should set this variable value under [mysqld] section as :

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
```

and restart MySQL service to have effect.

InnoDB buffer pool caches both data and index pages. You can set this value to 70-80% of available memory for Innodb-only installations

Comment: What if I have 1000GB ram? still %70-80 or near to %100? :)

Answer (score 0):

Look here [innodb_buffer_pool_size documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size)

In there it says this variable can be set in option-file (my.cnf) or on the command line when starting the server.

Also. I don't think you'll be able to assign the value of "system display" to this variable as it is a numeric. See the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I faced that same problem:

> ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' is a read only variable

Then I notice I wrote `[mysqly]` wrongly at the top, and that's why my.cnf was not working properly. I change it to `[mysqld]` and restart MySQL, then everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

To temporarily increase buffer pool size:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size= (SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size)*10
#check via this:
#SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024
```

To permanently increase, you will need to edit my.cnf file.  Here are my go to commands for ubuntu + mysql 8.

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

add in this at the bottom of the file

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 8G
```

save and exit. restart MySQL.

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```