# Online resizing of mysql 5.7.12

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am seeing below error when I tried to resize the mysql buffer pool dynamically.

```
mysql> set global innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2147483648;
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' is a read only variable
```

The mysql version I am using is

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.12    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

As per the documentation, `5.7.5` onwards, mysql allows dynamic resizing of the buffer pool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set global innodb\_buffer\_pool\_size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534144/how-to-set-global-innodb-buffer-pool-size)

Comment: I tested with MySQL 5.7.27 and it works. Perhaps it wasn't quite working in MySQL 5.7.12, which was an early GA release, dated 2016-04-11. Maybe it's time to upgrade your instance to a more current version?

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin . Makes sense to upgrade. I want to ensure if I missed some steps which is causing this error.